# Is there a nice characterization of those categories in which $a \subseteq b$ implies $a \leq b$?

Tags: category-theory

Given arrows $a:A \rightarrow Y$ and $b : B \rightarrow Y$, define that:

1. $a \subseteq b$ iff for all $Z$ and all $g,g' : Y \rightarrow Z$, we have:

$$gb=g'b \rightarrow ga=g'a$$

2. $a \leq b$ iff there exists $u : A \rightarrow B$ such that $a=bu.$

Then $a \leq b$ implies $a \subseteq b$, but not conversely. (By the way, does the relation $\subseteq$ have a conventional name, and is it discussed anywhere?)

Anyway, here's my question:

> **Question.** Is there a nice characterization of those categories in which $a \subseteq b$ implies $a \leq b$ for all arrows $a$ and $b$ having a common codomain? I am especially looking for something that is useful for determining which categories of algebraic structures have this property. (Perhaps they all have it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Condition 2 is the wrong condition to look at unless you put restrictions on $a$ and $b$ (e.g. that they are monomorphisms). Assume throughout the rest of this answer that the categories involved have finite limits and colimits.

Condition 1 can be rephrased as follows. There is a universal object $Z$ equipped with two maps $g, g'$ such that $g \circ b = g' \circ b$: it is the pushout of the diagram $Y \xleftarrow{b} B \xrightarrow{b} Y$, also known as the [cokernel pair](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel+pair) $\text{coker}(b)$. It is the correct substitute for the cokernel in non-abelian settings: in particular, it is trivial iff $b$ is an epimorphism. The first condition can then be restated as the condition that $ga = g'a$ where $g, g'$ are these two universal maps, or equivalently that $a$ factors through the equalizer $\text{eq}(g, g')$.

The equalizer of the cokernel pair is also called the [regular image](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image#AsEqualizer) $\text{im}(b)$; it gives a factorization $B \to \text{im}(b) \to Y$ of $b$ where the map $\text{im}(b) \to Y$ is a [regular monomorphism](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism), and $\text{im}(b)$ is universal with this property. Hence we can restate the two conditions as follows:

1. $a$ factors through $\text{im}(b) \to Y$.
2. $a$ factors through $B \to \text{im}(b) \to Y$.

Condition 1 is equivalent to the condition that the regular image $\text{im}(a) \to Y$ of $a$ factors through $\text{im}(b)$, which means it is really a condition on regular monomorphisms. In any category where regular monomorphisms are the same as monomorphisms, Condition 1 therefore reproduces the usual notion of containment of subobjects. (But regular monomorphisms already don't agree with monomorphisms for [commutative rings](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/).)

In the same way that there is a universal way to test Condition 1, there is a universal way to test the relationship between Condition 1 and Condition 2: taking $a$ to be the inclusion $\text{im}(b) \to Y$ itself shows that the two conditions are equivalent (for a fixed $b$) iff the map $B \to \text{im}(b)$ has a right inverse. Unfortunately there's no reason for this to be true in general even in an extremely nice category.

*Example.* Let the ambient category be the category of abelian groups (about as nice as it gets!) and let $b : \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ be the obvious quotient. The regular image of $b$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but the  quotient map $\mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ does not have a right inverse; equivalently, the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$$

does not split.

More generally, in an abelian category the map $B \to \text{im}(b)$ is an epimorphism and the regular image of any epimorphism is its codomain, so asking that every map of the form $B \to \text{im}(b)$ have a right inverse is equivalent to asking that every short exact sequence splits, which is equivalent to asking that the abelian category is semisimple.

On the other hand, Conditions 1 and 2 are clearly equivalent if the map $B \to \text{im}(b)$ is an isomorphism, or equivalently if $b$ is a regular monomorphism.

If you're interested in pursuing this further then I'd encourage you to learn more about your various options for defining [images](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image), since the intuition you seem to be trying to capture is "the image of $a$ is contained in the image of $b$."

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in some contexts regular monomorphisms arguably make a better notion of subobject than monomorphisms; for example, in $\text{Top}$ a monomorphism is just an injection but a regular monomorphism is an injection which is also a homeomorphism onto its image (exercise), so isomorphism classes of regular monomorphisms reproduces subspaces whereas monomorphisms gets you something a bit weirder, keeping track of all finer topologies on all subspaces as well.